# Set contentMode for Image inside Button in Swift

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimageview, contentmode

I am trying to `setImage` inside my `UIButton` but the image appears smaller inside the button although there is "free-space" and I also set the `contentMode`.

**Button:**

```
let noteButton: UIButton = {
    let v = UIButton()
    v.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "pencil"), for: .normal)
    v.tintColor = UIColor.white
    v.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return v
}()
```

**Constraints:**

```
noteButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    noteButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    noteButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: itemView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    noteButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: linkButton.leadingAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting image as background image inside the button?

Comment: I did and that "scales" the image but not in respect to its ratio

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. I just had to add these to lines:

```
v.contentHorizontalAlignment = .fill
v.contentVerticalAlignment = .fill
```